# query with multiple joins and indexes stuck on "Copying to tmp table"

Tags: mysql

I have this query that doesn't run under odd circumstances. It's doing two joins, I have two indexes of the same name on two different tables (but this shouldn't matter). When I remove one of the indexes from either tables, the query runs fine. Something else that makes it run is removing the order by clause, but I definitely need that. When I run show processlist the state is stuck on "Copying to tmp table". The indexes I'm talking about are channelID.

the query

```
SELECT twitterTweets.*, 
       COUNT(twitterRetweets.id) AS retweets, 
       sTwitter.followers, 
       sTwitter.date 
FROM   twitterTweets 
       LEFT JOIN twitterRetweets 
              ON twitterTweets.id = twitterTweetsID 
       JOIN sTwitter 
         ON DATE(twitterTweets.dateCreated) = sTwitter.date 
            AND twitterTweets.channelID = sTwitter.channelID 
WHERE  twitterTweets.channelID = 32 
       AND type = 'tweet' 
       AND DATE(dateCreated) >= '2013-12-05' 
       AND DATE(dateCreated) <= '2014-01-05' 
GROUP  BY twitterTweets.id 
ORDER  BY dateCreated
```

explain results

```
1   SIMPLE  sTwitter        ref channelID       channelID       5   const                   1162    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  twitterTweets   ref channelID       channelID       5   const                   17456   Using where
1   SIMPLE  twitterRetweets ref twitterTweetsID twitterTweetsID 5   social.twitterTweets.id 3
```

create for the three tables

```
CREATE TABLE `twitterTweets` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `clientID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `divisionID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `accountID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `channelID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` enum('tweet','reply','direct in','direct out') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT 'tweet',
  `subType` enum('reply beginning','retweet beginning','reply middle','retweet middle') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `tweetID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tweet` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `replies` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `hash` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `retweet` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `source` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `media` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `tweetUrls` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `expandedUrls` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `replyToStatus` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `followers` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `following` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updates` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `group1` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `campaign` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `segment` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `destination` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `retweets` smallint(6) DEFAULT '0',
  `favorites` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateCreated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateAdded` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateUpdated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `channelID` (`channelID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=296264 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `twitterRetweets` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `clientID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `divisionID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `accountID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `channelID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `twitterTweetsID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tweetID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `screenName` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `followers` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `following` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updates` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `favorites` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateAdded` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `twitterTweetsID` (`twitterTweetsID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=93821 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `sTwitter` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `clientID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `divisionID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `accountID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `channelID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `following` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `followers` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `updates` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `channelID` (`channelID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=35615 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

So how do I make this thing run with both indexes in place? Do I have to ignore one of them?

Comment: the reason it does not use your index is because you are using a function in your where clause namely date()

Comment: Yip you are not using SARGS in your query thus you cant use the index.

Comment: And EXPLAIN isn't smart enough to not include the index in the key column? How can I get around it?

Comment: Try:  `AND dateCreated >= '2013-12-05' AND dateCreated < '2014-01-06' `

Comment: Also try `ON twitterTweets.dateCreated >= sTwitter.date AND twitterTweets.dateCreated < sTwitter.date + interval 1 day ` instead of: `ON DATE(twitterTweets.dateCreated) = sTwitter.date`

Comment: @kordirko I changed my query with your suggestions, but I still get the same problem. Here's my current query:

Comment: `select twitterTweets.*, count(twitterRetweets.id) as retweets, sTwitter.followers, sTwitter.date from twitterTweets left join twitterRetweets on twitterTweets.id = twitterTweetsID join sTwitter on twitterTweets.dateCreated >= sTwitter.date AND twitterTweets.dateCreated < sTwitter.date + interval 1 day and twitterTweets.channelID = sTwitter.channelID where twitterTweets.channelID = 32 and type = 'tweet' and dateCreated >= '2013-12-05 00:00:00' and dateCreated <= '2014-01-05 23:59:59' group by twitterTweets.id order by dateCreated`